# Consuming a post method in WCF REST template 40 - JSON

Tags: json, wcf, rest

am getting rather frustrated at the lack of information out there on how to post data to a WCF REST method in JSON form. I have tried almost everything out there. Google is just returning purple links at this point...

What I am looking for is a way to send a JSON object to my method so it can shelve all of the data for me. What I am currently trying to get working is below:

The Method header:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "role/new", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
void AddNewRole(Stream streamdata)
```

The logic from the client app:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(role);
byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://IP/InfoService/role/new");
request.Method = "POST";
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("", "");
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
     sw.Write(json);
}
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
     MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Using this method I get an accepted response from the service, but it is a blank response and no new data gets added to the database. Granted, it is possible that there is a problem with my database update methods. Either way, can anyone help me figure out where I am going wrong?

EDIT: I now have fiddler able to test on the test client, and as expected there are problems with my DB queries. Ill post back soon.

EDIT2: Finally worked out the database problems, I have now successfully invoked through fiddler.

EDIT3: Its working now, thanks to nobody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above has been edited, it works.